# Share contact via mail and message in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I have contact's **_ID** and also all **Raw_contact_id** related to **_ID** of contact.

Now I want to share this contact via E-mail or text message.
So what Have to do?

- Is there any intent that can be used directly to share contact?
- If other way then please suggest me.

Comment: You can use Contact button which shows AlertDialog which contains list of contact when you select that contacts gets added to your email list. Hope this helps...  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used this code for it:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to));
```